# SQL Server 2008 filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, filter

I am joining 4 tables together from the same db. My query is returning the data i am after, but is also returning multiple rows for some records. I only want the row with the most recent LastReportedHrsDate for each WKO_WorkOrderID. Can someone help me with the correct code to filter?

Code (I am still pretty new to SQL..):

```
SELECT     dbo.PLT.PLT_ItemID, SUM(dbo.PLD.PLD_IssueQty) AS Issued, dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID, dbo.WKO.WKO_RequiredQty, dbo.WKO.WKO_CompleteQty, 
                      dbo.WKO.WKO_RequiredQty - dbo.WKO.WKO_CompleteQty AS openbalance, dbo.PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy, 
                      (dbo.WKO.WKO_CompleteQty * dbo.PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy - SUM(dbo.PLD.PLD_IssueQty)) * - 1 AS WIP, dbo.WKO.WKO_ItemID, dbo.WOO.WOO_StatusCode, 
                      dbo.WOO.WOO_LastReportedHrsDate, dbo.WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
FROM         dbo.PLT INNER JOIN
                      dbo.PLD ON dbo.PLT.PLT_RecordID = dbo.PLD.PLD_PLT_RecordID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.WKO ON dbo.PLT.PLT_WorkOrderID = dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.WOO ON dbo.PLT.PLT_WorkOrderID = dbo.WOO.WOO_WorkOrderID
WHERE     (dbo.WKO.WKO_StatusCode = N'Released') AND (dbo.PLT.PLT_ItemID = '9005-20-1794')
GROUP BY dbo.PLT.PLT_ItemID, dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID, dbo.WKO.WKO_RequiredQty, dbo.WKO.WKO_CompleteQty, dbo.PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy, dbo.WKO.WKO_ItemID, 
                      dbo.WOO.WOO_StatusCode, dbo.WOO.WOO_LastReportedHrsDate, dbo.WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
HAVING      (SUM(dbo.PLD.PLD_IssueQty) = dbo.WKO.WKO_RequiredQty * dbo.PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy) AND (dbo.WOO.WOO_LastReportedHrsDate IS NOT NULL) AND 
                      (dbo.WOO.WOO_StatusCode IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
```

Can't post a pic of my results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT      max(dbo.WOO.WOO_LastReportedHrsDate),dbo.PLT.PLT_ItemID, SUM(dbo.PLD.PLD_IssueQty) AS Issued, dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID, dbo.WKO.WKO_RequiredQty, dbo.WKO.WKO_CompleteQty, 
                      dbo.WKO.WKO_RequiredQty - dbo.WKO.WKO_CompleteQty AS openbalance, dbo.PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy, 
                      (dbo.WKO.WKO_CompleteQty * dbo.PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy - SUM(dbo.PLD.PLD_IssueQty)) * - 1 AS WIP, dbo.WKO.WKO_ItemID, dbo.WOO.WOO_StatusCode, 
                      dbo.WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
FROM         dbo.PLT INNER JOIN
                      dbo.PLD ON dbo.PLT.PLT_RecordID = dbo.PLD.PLD_PLT_RecordID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.WKO ON dbo.PLT.PLT_WorkOrderID = dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.WOO ON dbo.PLT.PLT_WorkOrderID = dbo.WOO.WOO_WorkOrderID
WHERE     (dbo.WKO.WKO_StatusCode = N'Released') AND (dbo.PLT.PLT_ItemID = '9005-20-1794')
AND (dbo.WOO.WOO_LastReportedHrsDate IS NOT NULL) AND (dbo.WOO.WOO_StatusCode IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY dbo.PLT.PLT_ItemID, dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID, dbo.WKO.WKO_RequiredQty, dbo.WKO.WKO_CompleteQty, dbo.PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy, dbo.WKO.WKO_ItemID, 
                      dbo.WOO.WOO_StatusCode, dbo.WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
HAVING      (SUM(dbo.PLD.PLD_IssueQty) = dbo.WKO.WKO_RequiredQty * dbo.PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy) 
ORDER BY dbo.WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! It returned an error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'dbo.WOO.WOO_LastReportedHrsDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. When i added the column to the Group By clause, it returned the same duplicated records.

Comment: As we are trying to take the max of WOO_LastReportedHrsDate column, it doesnt need to be in group by. I've edited my query, please try now.

Comment: A step closer for sure, but returning multiple WorkerOrders. I'm not quite sure why it is still returning multiple, when the query specifies the MAX. here are the results in .XLS in my public dropbox folder: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/77130984/results.xlsx

Comment: i manipulated it a bit more and added a MAX to the WorkCenterID and it worked as expected. thank you!