# A little filter/grouping help for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pulling from 4 different tables to gather this data. The information I want is being returned, however it is being duplicated dependent on the number of WorkCenterID's that the item has gone through. I want it to return the largest work center ID only.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT      PLT.PLT_ItemID
        ,   SUM(PLD.PLD_IssueQty) AS Issued
        ,   WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
        ,   WKO.WKO_RequiredQty
        ,   WKO.WKO_CompleteQty
        ,   WKO.WKO_RequiredQty - WKO.WKO_CompleteQty AS openbalance
        ,   PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy
        ,   (WKO.WKO_CompleteQty * PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy - SUM(PLD.PLD_IssueQty)) * - 1 AS WIP
        ,   WKO.WKO_ItemID
        ,   WKO.WKO_StatusCode
        ,   WKO.WKO_LastWorkDate
        ,   WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
FROM        PLT
                INNER JOIN PLD ON PLT.PLT_RecordID = PLD.PLD_PLT_RecordID
                INNER JOIN WKO ON PLT.PLT_WorkOrderID = WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN WOO ON PLT.PLT_WorkOrderID = WOO.WOO_WorkOrderID
WHERE       (WKO.WKO_StatusCode = N'Released')
        AND (PLT.PLT_ItemID = '1700-0535501-01')
GROUP BY    PLT.PLT_ItemID
        ,   WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
        ,   WKO.WKO_RequiredQty
        ,   WKO.WKO_CompleteQty
        ,   PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy
        ,   WKO.WKO_ItemID
        ,   WKO.WKO_LastWorkDate
        ,   WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
        ,   WKO.WKO_StatusCode
HAVING      (SUM(PLD.PLD_IssueQty) = WKO.WKO_RequiredQty * PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy)
ORDER BY    WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
```

Here are the results:

```
PLT_ItemID  Issued  WKO_WorkOrderID WKO_RequiredQty WKO_CompleteQty openbalance PLT_QtyPerAssy  WIP WKO_ItemID  WKO_StatusCode  WKO_LastWorkDate    WOO_WorkCenterID
1700-0535501-01 10  WO43620 10  10  0   1   0   9121-VA2-M  Released    2011-10-17 00:00:00.000 1010
1700-0535501-01 10  WO43620 10  10  0   1   0   9121-VA2-M  Released    2011-10-17 00:00:00.000 110
1700-0535501-01 10  WO43620 10  10  0   1   0   9121-VA2-M  Released    2011-10-17 00:00:00.000 810
1700-0535501-01 2   WO53259 2   2   0   1   0   9120-DE45R-M    Released    2012-03-05 00:00:00.000 110
1700-0535501-01 2   WO53259 2   2   0   1   0   9120-DE45R-M    Released    2012-03-05 00:00:00.000 810
1700-0535501-01 6   WO53697 6   6   0   1   0   9120-DE45-M Released    2012-03-30 00:00:00.000 110
1700-0535501-01 6   WO53697 6   6   0   1   0   9120-DE45-M Released    2012-03-30 00:00:00.000 810
1700-0535501-01 5   WO86275 5   0   5   1   5   9121-VA2-M  Released    2013-10-18 00:00:00.000 110
```

Comment: Related (from same OP): [SQL Server 2008 filtering](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18520563/211627)

Comment: What's your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() function. Like this:

```
WITH a AS (    
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITON BY WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID ORDER BY WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID) AS RowNo     
        ,   PLT.PLT_ItemID
        ,   SUM(PLD.PLD_IssueQty) AS Issued
        ,   WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
        ,   WKO.WKO_RequiredQty
        ,   WKO.WKO_CompleteQty
        ,   WKO.WKO_RequiredQty - WKO.WKO_CompleteQty AS openbalance
        ,   PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy
        ,   (WKO.WKO_CompleteQty * PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy - SUM(PLD.PLD_IssueQty)) * - 1 AS WIP
        ,   WKO.WKO_ItemID
        ,   WKO.WKO_StatusCode
        ,   WKO.WKO_LastWorkDate
        ,   WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
FROM        PLT
                INNER JOIN PLD ON PLT.PLT_RecordID = PLD.PLD_PLT_RecordID
                INNER JOIN WKO ON PLT.PLT_WorkOrderID = WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN WOO ON PLT.PLT_WorkOrderID = WOO.WOO_WorkOrderID
WHERE       (WKO.WKO_StatusCode = N'Released')
        AND (PLT.PLT_ItemID = '1700-0535501-01')
GROUP BY    PLT.PLT_ItemID
        ,   WKO.WKO_WorkOrderID
        ,   WKO.WKO_RequiredQty
        ,   WKO.WKO_CompleteQty
        ,   PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy
        ,   WKO.WKO_ItemID
        ,   WKO.WKO_LastWorkDate
        ,   WOO.WOO_WorkCenterID
        ,   WKO.WKO_StatusCode
HAVING      (SUM(PLD.PLD_IssueQty) = WKO.WKO_RequiredQty * PLT.PLT_QtyPerAssy)
)

SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.RowNo = 1
```

Selecting only the fields you like to actually return of course... :)

Comment: So i think this might help, What i am trying to accomplish is to pull a distinct workorder for each part number based on the largest workcenterID
So basically i would like to see 3 total records returned. one for each Workorder with the largest WorkcenterID

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you mean but I updated the query to partition the ROW_NUMBER() on WorkOrderId and Order it by WorkCenterID. This way you should be able to get the desired result (granted I understand what you want...) when SELECTing * WHERE RowNo = 1